# Supress on click event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, openlayers-6

This is an on-click function for the identifier button. This function will trigger a popup design function when the user clicks on some feature on the map. I want this click functionality on that feature to be suppressed when the user clicks the identifier button a second time. This means the identifier button should act like a start-stop switch.

This function is inside `useEffect()` and the `#IdentifierClick` is the id for the button which is in `return{}` part which will trigger the click event.

```
const IdentifierClick = () => {
            console.log("working");
            // clicktimes = clicktimes+1;
            // console.log("Button click times ",clicktimes)
                
                if((enableIdentify == false))
                {
                        initialMap.on('singleclick', function (evt) 
                        {
                            console.log(evt, "printevt");
                            var myLayerChecked;
                            console.log(layerlist, "printlayerlist");
                            for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) 
                            {
                                layerlist[1].values_.layers.array_[i].values_.layers.array_.forEach(arrayItem => {
                                    myLayerChecked = arrayItem.state_.visible;
                                    console.log("myLayerChecked", myLayerChecked);
                                    // console.log(layerlists,"printlayerlist");
                                    if (myLayerChecked == true) {
                                        document.getElementById('popup-content').innerHTML = '<p class="identifier_p"><b>Identifier Details</b></p>';
                                        console.log("My Array Data", arrayItem.values_.source)
                                        designHtml(evt, arrayItem.values_.source, arrayItem.values_.title);
                                        enableIdentify = true;
                                    }
                                    else 
                                    {
                                        console.log("No Layer is checked");
                                    }

                                });
                            }
                        })
                }
                else {
                    
                }
                
        });
```

The `intialMap.on('singleclick',function())` should be enabled and disabled by `IdentifierClick` function when we click to trigger the function. Please help me achieve this task.

Comment: Is this jQuery or react or both? Are you able to provide a working example?

Comment: @ksav this is both jquery and react

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery with react. They'll interfere with each other and prevent anything from working.

Comment: Okay, I will replace the jquery with a basic `const IdentifierClick()` function @mousetail. But still, my issue of what I want is still left unsolved.

Comment: If you want the `singleclick` callback to be run only the 1st time, try `one` instead of `on`. 
https://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: @NiceBooks thanks for the suggestion, but I want to disable the single-click event which will be triggered once I click it. Please suggest me something to unbind the single-click event completely.

Comment: Declare the event handler outside the function, & disable it using `off`. Eg: `$('div').off('singleclick', eventHandler)`
https://api.jquery.com/off/